# Problem with Math.Stackexange

Tags: support, mathjax

Since yesterday, I have the following problem with this site. On the top always appears the following sentence:

"Mathematics requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load."

I have already uninstalled firefox and reinstalled it, but the problem appears in every browser i am installing: Internet Explorer, Google Chrome, Firefox.

I checked, that Java Scriot is activated in Firefox and reinsalled Java. But nothing helps.

I also deleted the chronicle and cookies etc.

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps it is your anti-virus program. Has there been a recent update?

Comment: Nice. If I deactivate my Browser-safety in  antivir premium (my anti-virus programm), then it works. Thanks. But why does it works if i deactivate it? Should I deactivate it from now on, everytime I write something here? Or is there another solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Virus alert when opening mse questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3188/virus-alert-when-opening-mse-questions)

Comment: @Peter: send mail to the customer support for your anti-virus program. They shouldn't block legitimate websites.

Comment: @Peter: Do not deactivate!! There may be settings of the program that let you allow MSE.

Answer (score 3):

Since my comment seemed to be relevant, I will turn it into an answer.

Similar things have happened to me, though not with MSE. It was the anti-virus program, installing an "improved" update in the middle of the night.

I fixed the problem by fiddling with settings. Perhaps you can do that. I am not familiar with your anti-virus program, so cannot give specific instructions. But I am confident that a major program would have a setting that "allows" certain user-specified sites.

Do not disable your anti-virus program, even for a few minutes.

Comment: "Do not disable your anti-virus program, even for a few minutes." - **[Indeed, do not](https://isc.sans.edu/survivaltime.html) [do this!](https://isc.sans.edu/diary.html?storyid=4721).** This cannot be sufficiently emphasized.